# iOSのクライアントライブラリの更新方法について

Tags: ios

お世話になっております。

現在、GoogleCloudEndpointsを使用してクライアントアプリを作成しているのですが、
Endpoint APIに変更を加えた場合はクライアントライブラリも更新する必要があると
思うのですが、皆様どのようにクライアントライブラリを更新されていますでしょうか？

新しい、クライアントライブラリを再生成して、前回のクライアントライブラリをプロジェクトから
削除し、差し替える方法しか現状ないのでしょうか？

宜しくお願いいたします。

※google-cloud-endpointsのタグでは書き込みができませんでしたので、GAEで投稿させて
頂きました。